# Meteor: get template name in spacebars

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I started to develop a meteor webapp. I use meteor with iron routes and a main layout.html file that use yield.
In router.js i have:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
 });

Router.route('/login', {name: 'login'});
```

In layout.html:

```
<template name="layout">
    <div class="container">
       {{> header}}
        <main id="{{ actualLoadedTemplate }}">
            {{> yield}}
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

I would that the 'main' tag, have the id of the actual loaded template, "login" in this case.
Is there a way to accomplish that? Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just figured it out

```
Template.registerHelper('actualLoadedTemplate', function(){
    return Router.current() && Router.current().route.getName().replace('.','-');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

`templateName = template.view.name.replace('Template.', '')`

`template` is `Template.instance()` or `this` in `onCreated`, `onRendered`, `onDestroyed` callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You can define a template helper on your layout :

```
Template.layout.helpers({
  actualLoadedTemplate: function(){
    return Router.current() && Router.current().template;
  }
});
```

Comment: Just tried, but return always undefined. Maybe because the helper is called outside the loaded view?